# How to get last 3 days records from database without today?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code:

```
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

And result will be like this:

```
2022-05-12
2022-05-11
2022-05-10
```

But I want this:

```
2022-05-11
2022-05-10
2022-05-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a range here:

```sql
WHERE date < CURDATE() AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Assuming today's date be `2022-05-12`, the above logic would exclude this date but include the three previous days, from 11th May to 9th May.